# Hiding the Contents of a Header File

Tags: c++, header, include, header-files

I am a tutor and I'm trying to write something to help students learn C++. Suppose I have a .cpp file that includes two .h files, which we will call "solution.h" and "student_answer.h". The "solution.h" file contains a class called "Solution" which implements member functions and variables that solve a problem. Students are to implement their own solution to the same problem in a separate "student_answer.h" file, in a class which we will call "Student".

The .cpp file should then take the two class definitions, "Solution" (the class defined in solution.h) and "Student" (the class defined in student_answer.h), and run the two implementations to verify whether the student answer is correct, and it should provide detailed output in cases where the student answer has a bug. However, I want to be able to hide the contents of the solution.h file (or the "Solution" class) from the students while still providing them with the .cpp file that they can compile and run their own solution with.

Currently, I have something like this:

```
#include "solution.h"
#include "student_answer.h"

// ...

int main() {
   Solution s;
   Student a;
   // run member functions of s and a, compare results to verify if student
   // implementation is correct (and print helpful output if there is a bug)
   ...
}
```

Is there a way to do the same thing without having to reveal the solution.h file to the students? Is there a better approach to doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: C has no class types. The C tag is not applicable here.

Comment: Voting to close as POB.  That said, an easy way to do this is not not implement anything in `solution.h`.  Put the class declaration in `solution.h` and then have a `solution.cpp` where you actually define the implementation for `solution.h`.  This lets both you and the students have the same declaration and then you just point to your `solution.cpp`, or the student's `solution.cpp` when compiling.

Comment: Sure, solution should only hold the definitions and the implementation should come compiled in the form of a library (that is assuming you want them to be able to run it themselves). That way they can't look at the code.

Comment: Perhaps you should discover unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do the same thing without having to reveal the solution.h file to the students?

No.

Best you could do is to not put any implementation details into solution.h and instead provide a pre-compiled library for comparison. That would prevent students from seeing the solution except for the API, which is presumably part of instructions for the student anyway.

This does have a challenge that the pre-compiled library must be compatible with the systems that the students use. This can be solved by instructing the students to use a provided VM or container image.
However, this approach does not prevent the students from implementing their API by delegating to the solution API.

There's really no need to provide the correct solution. Write to solution for yourself only; write tests that are required to pass with either your solution or the student's; Test the tests with your solution; Provide only the tests to the students, not your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static or dynamic library of Solution.h, compile it, and link it with the project. The students now get the header of the solution with declarations, but not definitions.
The library topic is a little bit too complex to explain in one answer. Watch the video from TheChernoProject ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wt4dxDNmDA8 ) for it.
Another way would be, making the code unreadable (defines) or put it in asm blocks.